# Is keeping macbook battery 20%~80% good?

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, charge

I heard that keeping macbook battery in 20% to 80% is good.

Is it true? or what is the best way to use macbook best way?

Comment: Wondering the same thing - I used charge my MacBook Pro 100% and keep it that way all the time until recently when someone told me to use the batter charge. Wondering if having it plugged in always a good idea.

Comment: +1 to you and the answerer - let's direct everyone to some great existing posts that should cover all aspects of this. If after reviewing them all, it's fine to make a substantial edit here showing how your question is different than the others and we can get this reopened. Thanks for phrasing this excellent question - linking it with the others will help people searching for exactly the words how you describe this. Since you didn't find the other questions, others won't without this linking

Answer (score 2):

## Apple Lithium-ion Batteries

See https://www.apple.com/batteries/ and https://www.apple.com/batteries/maximizing-performance/ for Apple's authoritative recommendations.

> They’re inside every iPhone, iPad, iPod, Apple Watch, MacBook, and AirPods, helping you do all kinds of things in all kinds of places. Find out more about your battery to get the most out of it throughout its lifespan — and beyond.